# Can someone show me a Java code example where the modifier strictfp makes a difference?

Tags: java, precision

I've been trying to write a Java method which answers a different result if it has the strictfp modifier or if it has not. I failed to write such method so far, despite trying some various rounding on double arithmetic on multiple machines with different processors.

I have access through my company build/test infrastructure to VMs with Intel, ARM and MIPS processors. It's not clear to me what exact version of each processor is available, or whether they're available through VMs actually running on Intel machines, but I'm interested in fairly recent processors (let's say less than 8 years old. I don't care about procs from the past century).

Can someone write me a Java method which answers a different result if it has the strictfp modifier or if it has not? Can that person explain me what kind of machine, using a processor released in the past 8 years it has to run on for the difference to show up?

In addition, is there any processor released today for an Android device, laptops or desktops where the strictfp modifier makes a difference?